# Does DbLinq supports SQLite3?

Tags: sqlite, dblinq

I have a small project that requires minimal storage. So i choose SQLite3. I'm not much familiar with LINQ. I noticed DBLinq supports Linq. But i'm not sure that supports SQLite3 as DBLinq stooped development long ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'official' [SQLite ADO.NET provider](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) supports LINQ.